# KVM to Ovirt VM migration

Tags: kvm, migration, ovirt

I installed ovirt on a machine that was already hosting KVM virtual machines. I am now trying to migrate those VMs over to RHEV format, but I am receiving SASL authentication errors using virt-v2v.

I am not being prompted for credentials upon running the command

```
virt-v2v Windows7.xml -o rhev -os host.domain.net:/home/images --network ovirtmgmt Windows7
```

The error is

```
virt-v2v: Failed to connect to qemu:///system: libvirt error code: 45, message: authentication failed: Failed to step SASL negotiation: -7 (SASL(-7): invalid parameter supplied: Unexpectedly missing a prompt result)
```

This has been driving me crazy all night. Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

Vdsm uses its own credentials under ovirt, I don't really remember them so you'd better ask on users@ovirt.org. last I checked it was rhevh/shibboleth